# Can we apply selection over projection in relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

Here is the schema for works table
(PersonName,age,companyname,rating)

Now I want all the tuples whose name is megha and works in the company mtbank

I know I can do it like this:

```
π personName, age (σ companyName="M&T Bank" and personName="megha"(works))
```

But can we do it like this:

```
π personname, age (σ personName="megha" (π personName, age (σ companyName="M&T Bank" (works)))
```

Can we can apply selection over projection like this?

Comment: Hi. Do what, like how? Please explain yourself. You haven't said what that code is supposed to do. For "selection over projection", give an argument one way or the other and/or how you would approach this and/or something relevant from your textbook. Give a referenc to or definition of the relational algebra version you are supposed to use. Please read & act on [mcve], also [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Hi. You can contact an asker, answerer or commenter via [`@user` notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019). (Eg to tell me you edited.) Please look at the formatted output before you finish editing a post. You can see edits by clicking on the 'edited' link. (I just formatted your code again.) "I" is always capitalized. PS Please read my last comment. Show some research/effort. Why do you think they give the same result? Why do you think they are different? Also, you seem to *want* to ask, does this *particular* reordering of projection & select/restrict give the same answer.

Comment: A justified answer to this must talk about how π & σ act. For you to accept what an answer says based on how they act, you have to agree with some definitions of how they act. So you need to give some definitions that you understand. Otherwise answers have to guess & hope that you understand & accept their definitions.

Comment: Hi. Your question is improved. But notice that the outer `π personname, age` in the second query has no effect. Why is it there? Maybe you are somehow using a `π` with each `σ` or `σ` conjunct; but you don't *explain* what "like this" means so how can we answer your question? We can talk about when projection & selection can be done in reverse order but we don't know if that's all you want to know about.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you can't *nest expressions* is if the input is illegal for the operator. Eg division by zero in arithmetic. Eg relational union, intersection or difference of two relations with different headings. Eg projecting on missing attributes or restriction/selection on a condition mentioning a missing attribute.

The particulars depend on what version of relational algebra (relations & operators) you are talking about and the range of values your relation names can stand for.